# Not able to find Solution for :django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: django

Need help in understanding what I am doing wrong:
Relates to Django framework,
I am trying to map base url to view: here is url.py of app: https://www.screencast.com/t/DODOUYBhYK
here is urls.py of the main project: 
https://www.screencast.com/t/NjjFQ9HQ
When I used: `python manage.py makemigrations learninglogs` (learninglog is the app) , I got this error

```
(venv) C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log>python manage.py makemigrations learninglogs
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 535, in url_patterns
iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 350, in execute
self.check()
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 67, in _load_all_namespaces
namespaces.extend(_load_all_namespaces(pattern, current))
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 542, in url_patterns
raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'learninglogs.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\PycharmProjects\\Learning_Log\\learninglogs\\urls.py'>' does not a
ppear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

and when I removed the underscore from `url_patterns`, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/Learning_Log/learninglog/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 213, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 526, in _setup
    AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 150, in get_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Learning_Log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It's `urlpatterns`, *not* `url_patterns`.

Comment: as the error says, you likely did not add all apps to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: I edited the question on removing underscore from url_patterns another issue appeared I tried finding the solution for it before but nothing worked, traceback for the new issue is given in the post.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/bvKRunJE all apps are added in insalled apps settings

Comment: @Sidah: the name of your app is `learninglog`, not `learninglogs`...